# tcpdump loses connection

Tags: networking, unix, tcpdump

I'm on Ubuntu – but it's the same on Debian. I'm using `tcpdump` in order to track the connection of computers on my private network. At some point, the internet connection of the computers launching the script is lost as well as the targeted computers.

Here's the command line:

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 -A src host IP_TARGET
```

I tried with netsniff-ng, but the issue is the same.

The script that I refer to deviates the connection from the targeted computers to my computer (by sending ARP request) and `grep` the cookies from the output of `tcpdump`.

Comment: Hello Zack, it isn't clear from your question what the setup is - can you add some detail?  By "script" are you referring to tcpdump, or some other script?  Is connection to the server running tcpdump failing?  [edit] the question if you have more info.

Comment: I edited the question. Also, it is the connection to the server running tcpdump who fails.

Comment: You are spoofing arp to get response packets destined for one computer to go to another?  And you don't expect connections to be lost?

Comment: When I get the response packets, I read them then redirect them to the router. The connection isn't always lost. Sometimes it's immediately, sometimes it's after a few minutes.

Comment: Without more information, the only answer you are going to get is "you are messing with the traffic flows, and this is causing the connection drops".  I would recommend [edit]ing again, and putting in all the details of what you are doing and how, what macs you are spoofing - and what macs the packets have at each stage.